# programmatically sending text message - set expiration

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to set a text message's (SMS/MMS) expiration date programmatically, or is there a way to send a message that automatically deletes itself through java on android?

I can't seem to find any examples other than applications/websites that work as a middle man, and I would prefer for the end user (receiver) not be required to have the application installed.

**For anyone else that gets here --- it looks like the only way that it is possible is to have a middle man that actually manages the messages**

Comment: I don't think it is possible. To delete such timestamp tagged messages, as I know, there should be a running background service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such feature as a text-SMS which delete himself afer a certain amount of time.
If you send text-SMS it is very likely to appear in the user inbox, and will only be deleted manually by the user.

If you want your SMS to delete themselves, you'll need to make an application for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean deleteSms(String smsId) {
    boolean isDelSms = false;
    try {
        mActivity.getContentResolver().delete(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/" + smsId), null, null);
        isDelSms = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        isDelSms = true;
    }
    return isDelSms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean deleteSms(String smsId) {

    boolean isDelSms = false;

    try {

        mActivity.getContentResolver().delete(

                Uri.parse("content://sms/" + smsId), null, null);


        isDelSms = true;

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countryCode,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        isDelSms = true;

    }

    return isDelSms;

}
```